# How to filter a queryset for dates matching a given day?

Tags: python, django, datetime

I am trying to build a query for a view in Django in which I want to retrieve rows with today date (no matter the time).

I was thinking in a range between current date and datetime.datetime.now()

However I can't get only the date but not the time.

I have this:

```
now = datetime.datetime.now()
today = datetime.datetime.today()
var = Example.objects.filter(date__gt=datetime.date(today.year(), today.month(), today.day()), fecha__lt=now)
```

Comment: To get just the date from an existing `datetime` value, use the `.date()` method on that object.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
today = datetime.datetime.today()
Example.objects.filter(
    date__year=today.year, 
    date__month=today.month, 
    date__day=today.day
)
```

Comment: "Unresolved Reference" for "today". So correct is : datetime.today().year, datetime.today().mon... . Moreover, do not forget: "from datetime import datetime", otherwise you get the "unresolved" again. BTW, "today()" and "now()" are equal.

Comment: @Timo `today` refers to the local variable in the OP's question

Answer (score 2):

Grab rows that have a create date greater than the current date using only the date() method of the datetime.now() class.

```
where row.createdate > datetime.datetime.now().date()
```

Answer (score 1):

This should work.

```
import datetime
from django.db import models
from django.utils import timezone

class ExampleManager(models.Manager):
    def today(self):
        return super(ExampleManager, self).get_queryset().filter(pub_date__gte=datetime.datetime.today().date())

class ExampleModel(models.Model):
    # ...
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    objects = ExampleManager()
```